# Espresso Testing: Accessing Variables

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm writing data driven testing of my android app, and have begun writing a CSV to espresso testing framework which will allow me to quickly design and alter tests. Espresso can verify basic things about the UI such as successful clicks and text entry, but can it handle more advanced logic?

For example, I'm attempting to create a receipt based on some clicks that are made during the test. This will have been costed before runtime and entered into the CSV for automatic comparison of actual vs expected outcomes. In order to do this, I will need to access the receipt object to check its values? Or at least the textbox which displays it (easy, but not really what I'm after).

So, is there any way to get objects stored in memory from the main application into the espresso testing framework?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question.

In order to get to any objects/variables, you need to get to a class in which they exist. This is achieved in espresso with the @Rule tag:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);
```

From here you can do:

```
mainActivityTestRule.getActivity();
```

and from there all objects can be accessed

EDIT:

Primitives seem to come through fine, but I'm still trying to confirm if objects are actually passed through. It seems that the objects that are in my Espresso class are default, as though the constructor has just been run. Will update with more info.

Edit 2:

This does NOT work for objects. Putting a break-point in the espresso class and one in the main application and comparing them shows different object IDs. Getting the object from the main application doesn't return the object in the same state.